# Use Django ORM to select rows if a value is in a range stored in columns

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I apologize for the phrasing, I'm just not sure how to express this idea. It might make more sense if you have a look at my query:

```
SELECT * FROM geoip_table
WHERE inet '68.180.194.242' BETWEEN start_ip AND end_ip
LIMIT 1;
```

I'm using a GeoIP database that has ip ranges stored in the columns `start_ip` and `end_ip`. The above query works and is quite performant, I'm just interested to know if it is possible to write an equivalent query using Django's ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest reverting the logic of the "WHERE" clause. Provided that you have a suitable IP field, a query may look like this:

```
GeoIP.objects.filter(start_ip__lte='68.180.194.242', end_ip__gte='68.180.194.242')
```

For other similar cases, when this "reverting" is not possible, Django provides [F objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.F) (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) for examples of usage in queries)

Comment: That works, I suppose, but with significantly reduced performance. Thanks, though.